# How to display encoded HTML as decoded in MVC 3 Razor?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

I'm using Razor in MVC 3 and Asp.net C#.

I have a View with the following code. `model.ContentBody` has some HTML tags.

I would need display this HTML content as **DECODED**.

How shall I change my code in the View?

```
 <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ContentBody)
 </div>
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.Raw(Model.ContentBody)
</div>
```

This code solved the problem!

Comment: You'll want to be careful with that one, it blindly trusts the text and puts it to the page as a string.  What if Model.ContentBody was equal to `<script> window.location.href="badGuyNeighborhood.com" </script>`

Comment: @Andy Raddatz  thanks for your tip, in my case all content is sanitized and safe from db.

Answer (score 49):

`@Html.Raw` was not work for me here is example:-

```
  string name = "&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-size: small; color: #ff0000;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-size: small;&quot;&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;span style=&quot;font-size: large; color: #000000;&quot;&gt;Hi&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&amp;nbsp; &lt;br /&gt;This is just a sample,&lt;br /&gt;This will not work with @Html.Raw(),&lt;br /&gt;";
  <span>@Html.Raw(name);</span>
```

But this worked instead:-

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@model.ContentBody))
```

or you can also use :-

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@model.ContentBody));
```

Comment: It seems really verbose, why do not use just Html.Raw ??

Comment: @GibboK `MvcHtmlString.Create()` is more semantic IMO, although either solution will work for you.

Comment: @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@model.ContentBody));  This code worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: The Html.Raw doesn't work for me -- however even still It's a security hazard for my purposes. The MvcHtmlString.Create does work, could you please explain any similarities to Html.Raw and whether or not the String.Create is more protective? (I need to populate a word from my model into a Javascript function)

Comment: for hours I've been fiddling with CKEditor to get it to display the encoded text IT created to bypass ASP security, kinda crazy. @MvcHtmlString.Create(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@model.ContentBody)) finally worked!

Comment: Raw doesn't decode. So if your html looks like this:   `&lt;br/&gt;` you will just see the HTML as text.

Comment: ```HttpUtility.HtmlDecode``` was really helpful for me.

Answer (score 8):

You could also decode html in the controller before sending the model to the view,

> **WebUtility.HtmlDecode()**

```
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var content = _contentRepository.GetContent(id);
        var classViewModel = new ClassViewModel
                                 {
                                     ContentBody = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(ClassViewModel.ContentBody)
                                 };
        return View(classViewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, to summarize..
In my service/Controller, while returning the model to the view

```
    ....
    Description = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(narration.Narration1)
```

My cshtml, where the tinyMCE is displayed.. just bind regularly (I was using HtmlAttributeHelper for other purpose. You can ignore it)

```
 <div>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, HtmlAttributeHelper.ConditionalDisable(false, new {@class = "tinymce"}))
 </div>
```

And in the cshtml page where the data is displayed..

```
 ......
 <td class="col-word-wrap">@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@item.Narration1))</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use to display Html use with decode.

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(@Model.OurVision)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass in "ContentBody" as MvcHtmlString to your model instead of a string.

This way you can just use:

```
<div class="display-field">
        @model.ContentBody
 </div>
```

in your controller to get a MvcHtmlString just use:

```
MvcHtmlString myHtmlString = MvcHtmlString.Create("htmlcodeandtext");
```

Answer (score 0):

The string may also be URL Encoded, so to decode you do:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(string))
```

Answer (score -7):

**Use this code in the controller:**

```
string noHTML = Regex.Replace(inputHTML, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", "").Trim();
```